# Inline style works without quotes

Tags: html, css, styles, quotes, inline-styles

I have , for example , [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qeBZk/) . You can clearly see I am missing the quotes in the inline-style , but still it does show up correctly . From wherever I have learned , never did they say that not using quotes is allowed . So , is this:

- A bug in jsFiddle
- An intended feature . If so , then why we are taught to use the quotes.
- (Something that you may suggest)

### Reference Code:

#### index.html

```
<div style=background-color:red></div>This styling is weird
```

#### stylesheet.css

```
div{ height:500px ; width:500px }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because there is no space in row

Comment: According to HTML specifications, you can use simple quotes, double quotes, or simply omit the quotes

Comment: style=background-color:red this row hasn't space. If you add any space (style=background-color: red) property will not work. Use quotes style="background-color: red"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quotes for HTML attributes are considered optional (for HTML, not XHTML), however there are some cases where you may run into some problems.

e.g.

```
<a title=Hi, mom! href=#>
```

This isn't valid because of the space between 'Hi' and 'mom!'. Quotes group the statement together.

```
<div rel=a&b></div>
```

Rel value seen as "a&b" in all modern browsers including IE 9 and 10. IE 6, 7, and 8 see the value as "a".

More examples can be found here:
http://css-tricks.com/problems-with-unquoted-attributes/

Comment: Optional in HTML, so long as it's not XHTML, which DOES require valid xml and thus quoted attributes.

Answer (score 4):

You might run into problems when your attribute contents contain white space etc. From the HTML spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2):

> In certain cases, authors may specify the value of an attribute
>   without any quotation marks. The attribute value may only contain
>   letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), hyphens (ASCII decimal 45),
>   periods (ASCII decimal 46), underscores (ASCII decimal 95), and colons
>   (ASCII decimal 58). We recommend using quotation marks even when it is
>   possible to eliminate them.

Answer (score 0):

According to HTML specifications, you can use simple quotes, double quotes, or simply omit the quotes.

In XHTML, attribute values must always be quoted.

More infos :

1. [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2)
2. [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-unquoted)
3. [XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.4)