# Css not applying in drupal 7

Tags: html, css, drupal

I created some basic pages. In one basic page I had written 4 html div's and i installed cssinjector module . when I'm writing  css code in cssinjector it's not applying on width and height in  html code.

My html code  is

```
<div class=box1> </div>                           
<div class=box2> </div>                          
<div class=box3> </div>
```

My css code

```
.box1 { 
 width:300px; 
 height:230px; 
} 
.box2 {
 width:300px; 
 height:230px; 
} 

.box3 { 
 width:300px; 
 height:230px; 
}
```

Comment: find your box1 classed div in your browser make right click and choose inspect element, then you can see developer tools, from there in the right panel, check the styles and see your css code loaded or not ? if loaded it is probably overriding your class so at that point try this width:300px !important

Comment: No quote marks surrounding class names in the HTML...could be a thing?

Comment: @Paulie_D, Since we have a single class here (thus no emtpy space),  no need of quote marks. You actually would, if several classes where applied. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/18765363/195812

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for giving the reply,

Now its working for me I had changed my css code in css Injector and i changed html code like

```css
.box 
{
    margin: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 230px;
    display: inline-block;   
    background-color: rgb(20, 104, 168);
    border: 3px solid white;
   
}
```

```html
<div class=box> </div>                           
<div class=box> </div>                          
<div class=box> </div>
```